# Visualize loss and gain of share to competition

Tags: python, visualization

I have a dataset where I capture daily sales across different companies. What can be an intuitive visualization that captures which companies are gaining when Company 1 is losing its market share? For example, if Company 1 sees a drop of 5% from Day 1 to Day 2, I want to see which companies are gaining on this loss.